# How to extract the Starting characters from a String?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have a column UserID, value in column starts with D, SIN, SUD example

D4568732

SIN454544

SUD4545454

How to extract this starting pattern in C#?

Comment: Yes some values contain that pattern at a start some not...

Comment: yes I ignore those values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression like this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("SIN454544", "^D|SIN|SUD")
```

Comment: Will this work if My Patterns are at random Places in a starting, I mean not at a start @ middle

Comment: Solution above will only work if the string starts with the pattern. Leave out the ^ to make it work at any position. System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("34534SIN454544", "D|SIN|SUD")

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

You can try this to remove alphabets from string & result would be in digits only

```
 string input = "ABC12345";   
 var result = Convert.ToInt32(new String(input.Where(p => Char.IsNumber(p)).ToArray()));
```

**Solution 2**

Another possible answer would be this(Here it just skipping the alphabets from your input string)

```
 string input = "ABC12345";
 string result = new String(input.SkipWhile(p => Char.IsLetter(p)).ToArray());
```

Comment: You will need to add a `.SkipWhile(Char.IsLetter)` as well. And maybe explain why this works, for a nice answer

Comment: Yeah! than that would be another possible answer.

Comment: You probably meant `.ToArray()` in those code examples, instead of `.ToString()`.

Comment: Can't I go with .ToString()?

Comment: Sorry, but wasn't the question : "How to extract this starting pattern in C#?" in solution 1 `result` is a `string.Empty` and in the second I get the numbers

Answer (score 0):

The regex apply for handing string like below

```
        string str = "SIN454544";

        var matches=Regex.Match(str,"^([A-Z]+)\\d+");

        var patten = matches.Groups[1].Value;
```

"[A-Z]+" match any english character and "d+" match any number,the "()" will fetch 
match value from groups